# Program crashes when using delete

Tags: c++, valgrind

I've got this weird issue when using valgrind which confuses me alot.
im running on ubuntu18.04, c++17, valgrind version 3.13.0

consider this struct:

```
struct KelvinLine {
    float m;
    float b;
    float epsilon;

    KelvinLine() {
        m = 0;
        b = 0;
        epsilon = 0;
    }
};
```

my test main looks something like this:

```
int main(){
    auto arrLen = 10;
    KelvinLine* kelvinArray = new KelvinLine[arrLen];
    
    delete kelvinArray;
    return 0;

}
```

when running it without valgrind everything is ok, but once running with valgrind it crashes it with unhandled instruction error, if instead of new i use malloc (with the proper size of the struct array that i wanted) it continues its run like normal.
has anyone dealt with this issue before?
thanks

**Edit:**
fixed this issue by disabling AVX512F in my cmake

Comment: Probably unrelated but `delete kelvinArray` should be `delete[] kelvinArray`.

Comment: @G.M. I think it is related. He invokes UB, so it crashes with Valgrind, but might do sth else without.

Comment: If you can, get a more recent Valgrind. 3.13 is old.

Comment: Also AVX512 is not supported. There are patches on https://bugs.kde.org but they haven't made it into the source tree yet.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst mixing `delete` and `delete []` is UB, in cases like this (almost a POD struct) then it is likely to be harmless and never cause a crash.

The main difference between these two operators is that the array form will call the destructor on each element whilst the scalar form will only call it once (the first element if it is an array). That can potentially result in a resource leak. After calling the destructor, the memory for the instance/array gets freed. At least for the two implementations that I'm somewhat familiar with (llvm and GCC) that just means a call to `free()`.

Since this struct has no user-defined destructor the two forms of `operator delete` are essentially equivalent.

That said, this isn't safe to assume in general and there is no reason not to call the correct `operator delete []`.

Comment: Perhaps you could emphasize on the beginning that it is UB from a C++ standard perspective, but harmless in specific implementations, where it has defined misbehavior (destructor called only for first element of the array, but whole array freed from heap). UB for itself is never harmless ... It gets clear in your following paragraphs. But there is no guarantee in the standard that new/delete use malloc/free or that you can delete an array with simple delete (the two allocations new and new ...[] could be implemented differently).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're deallocating the memory using incorrect *delete expression* leading to **undefined behaivor**. Since you've used the array form of *new expression*, you must use the corresponding array form of *delete expression* as well:

```
//-----vv------------->use array form of delete expression
delete []kelvinArray;
```