# Why runtime error when using delete to free memory

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor, delete-operator, default-constructor

I think it has to do with memory allocation issues, but there is a destructor   there to free the memory of the object t of type A.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

struct A {
  int* i;
  A() { i = new int[3]; }
 ~A() { delete i; }
};

int main() {
  A t;
}
```

Comment: See [Rule of Three/Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) at minimum. But you've also paired a `new[]` with a non-array `delete`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197838/program-crashes-when-calling-constructors), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72870386/why-the-destructor-is-called-only-one-time-when-the-constructor-is-called-5-time/72870456?noredirect=1#comment128708410_72870456)

Answer (score 0):

```
~A() { delete i; }
```

should be

```
~A() { delete []i; }
```

Comment: Could've closed this as a dupe. There are plenty of dupes for this and this question is asked very often.

Comment: Voting to delete [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32182420).